# help mounting network storage drive

Tags: networking, ubuntu, backup, samba, storage

i have a windows share that i am trying to copy stuff over to from a bash script.

i can browse to the network share through KDE's "network" browser, but am not sure how do to access this filesystem from a shell.

should i be using "net use" or mount ...  ?

i tried mount -t smbfs //etc /mnt/backup but that came back with some errors.

basically i want to be able to "cp stuff.file /mnt/networkdrive"

edit: these are the errors: (using ubuntu intrepid)

```
mount -t cifs //dlink-642ea6/Volume_1 /mnt/backup
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on //dlink-642ea6/Volume_1,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
   need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)



  dmesg | tail
  [1813703.574971]  CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -22
```

Comment: What were the errors?

Answer (score 1):

i managed to get it working.  i had to install the packages that contained mount.cifs ( i think it was smbfs) thenwas able to run

```
  mount.cifs //192.168.1.106/Volume_1 /mnt/backup/
```

now off to find mount.cifs  for sunos and fedora

Answer (score 0):

If you're not on a domain, I'd try using something like

sudo mount -t cifs //windowsIP/sharename /mnt/mountpoint

That's with Ubuntu. Then just copy the files from/to the /mnt/mountpoint directory, assuming it exists.